# Call generic method on interface implementation only if implemented in C#

Tags: c#, generics, methods

Given a generic, contravariant interface:

```
public interface DoThis<in TParam> where TParam : Param
{
    void Do(TParam param);
}
```

That has a constraint around `Param`, a marker interface:

```
public interface Param { }
```

Where a concrete implementation exists:

```
public class TheClass : DoThis<Concrete1>, DoThis<Concrete2>
{
    public void Do(Concrete1 param) => Console.WriteLine("Called Concrete1");
    public void Do(Concrete2 param) => Console.WriteLine("Called Concrete2");
}
```

Where the Param implementations just demonstrate this scenario:

```
public class Concrete1 : Param { }

public class Concrete2 : Param { }
  
public class Concrete3 : Param { }
```

### Question

Is it possible to build a list of parameters and test whether the class implements the particular interface and call it, preferably without reflection?

Is it possible to get the `Non-reflective way using ref - call in a loop` to work below?

```
TheClass c = new TheClass();

Param[] @params = {new Concrete1(), new Concrete2(), new Concrete3()};

foreach (var p in @params)
{
    c.Do(p);
}
```

Of course the above won't compile.

#### Reflective Solution

We can look at [reflection] to do this...

```
foreach (var p in @params)
{
    MethodInfo? method = c.GetType()
        .GetMethods()
        .FirstOrDefault(
            x => x.Name == nameof(DoThis<Param>.Do)
            && x.GetParameters().Length == 1
            && x.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == p.GetType());
                
    method?.Invoke(c, new object[] {p});
}
```

Console Output:

```
Called Concrete1
Called Concrete2
```

#### Non-reflective way using ref

This does not quite work.

```
private void DoParam<TParam>(TheClass c, TParam @event) 
    where TParam : Param
{
    DoParam(ref c, ref @event);
}

private void DoParam<TParam>(ref TheClass c, ref TParam @event)
    where TParam : Param
{
    if (c is DoThis<TParam> projects)
    {
        projects.Do(@event);
    }
}
```

##### Call in a loop

The following loop passes Param as the type resulting in no console output:

```
foreach (var p in @params)
{
    DoParam(c, p);
}
```

##### Call directly

However, this does output to the console:

```
DoParam(c, new Concrete1());
DoParam(c, new Concrete2());
DoParam(c, new Concrete3());
```

Output:

```
Called Concrete1
Called Concrete2
```

Comment: You made `TheClass` responsible for supplying an implementation of `Do` for every individual subclass of `Param`. That feels wrong. How about implementing `Do` in `Concrete1`, `Concrete2`, `Concrete3`? Or if you prefer to keep those classes clean, introduce separate classes `Doer1`, `Doer2`, `Doer3` referenced by the concrete parameter classes? If necessary, inject (part of) `TheClass` into those new classes or into each `Do` method.

Comment: @RuudHelderman  - I am thinking around projections with events.  Therefore the event could be applied to a read model or an entity.  I really didn't want to pollute an event where it would be applied to - so just kept the concept very basic in this question.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible without reflection or other hacky approaches.
But you can check all types using the following approach:

```
            TheClass c = new TheClass();

            Param[] @params = { new Concrete1(), new Concrete2(), new Concrete3() };

            foreach (var p in @params)
            {
                if (p is Concrete1 c1 && c is DoThis<Concrete1> t1) t1.Do(c1);
                else if (p is Concrete2 c2 && c is DoThis<Concrete2> t2) t2.Do(c2);
                else if (p is Concrete3 c3 && c is DoThis<Concrete3> t3) t3.Do(c3);
            }
```

I would not recommend this, however, because this code has to be manually expanded again and again when new "Concrete" classes are added. This can easily be forgotten.